# Running RShiny from a Google cloud platform VM

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, shiny, virtual-machine, firewall

I've put together an R shiny doc that I want to run on my google cloud platform virtual machine. When I run the script, it works in that it generates a webpage "Listening on [http://127.0.0.1:6840"](http://127.0.0.1:6840%22). However, when I click on the link generated via the script, I get the error "500. That’s an error."

The script works locally so I don't believe it's an issue with the code.

Help!

Comment: hi, what is it you are trying to achieve, do you want to expose your R server to the internet?

Comment: Did you check the firewall rules both in GCP and the VM? Also, please provide the documentation you used on your setup for a better understanding on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to make it work. Full disclosure - I have no idea what any of this is, just following the steps in the docs:

- install R
- install Shiny
- clone https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples
- cd into any of the examples (I chose 050-kmeans-example)
- run `R -e "shiny::runApp(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)"` (8080 is just an example and can certainly be different) to start the server
- Receive a message in the console saying "Listening on [http://0.0.0.0:8080"](http://0.0.0.0:8080%22)
- Go back to the GCP and configure a firewall rule to allow communications to port 8080 from the outside world.
- Open a new browser tab with external ip address of the VM and append the port (e.g if the VM ext IP is 1.2.3.4, type in http://1.2.3.4:8080)